# What is the URL for a new Azure Git repos if the project is in Visual Studio on my local machine?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

What is the URL for a new Azure DevOps Git repos if the project is in Visual Studio on my local machine? Where do you get this URL?

Comment: You have to decide what the URL is going to be, by figuring out what the address is of the remote repository to which you will be pushing your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Import project code from local machine to Azure Repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334570/how-to-import-project-code-from-local-machine-to-azure-repos)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that your project already exists locally and you want to push it to Azure's Git service, then:

1. Create a new repo from the Azure console.

[image]

2. From the top right corner, click the ***Clone*** button.

[image]

3. Copy the HTTPS or SSH URL (depending on your preferred method). It should be something like `https://[user]@dev.azure.com/[org|user]/[project]/_git/[repo]` or `git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/[user|org]/[project]/[repo]` respectively.

[image]

4. In your local terminal, run

```
git remote add origin [url]
```

Where `url` is the URL for your repo copied from the Azure console.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the repo locally (such as via `git init`), it's **not** in Azure DevOps/VSTS.

You'll need to create a repo in Azure DevOps/VSTS, add a remote in your local repo, and push your local repo to the server.

When you create an empty repo in Azure DevOps/VSTS, it will give you precise instructions for how to do this.

Comment: I don't know how to: 
 * create an empty repo in Azure DevOps without a URL 
 * formulate the URL for the empty repro
 * or push my local repo to the server

I just want to put my VS project code into Azure DevOps repo.
How does one do this?
Why is it so difficult to do (many steps, not well documented) ?

Comment: @DonBaechtel When you create the repo, it will give you the URL.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-new-repo?view=vsts

Comment: Let's go back to the original question.
I have a project locally in Visual Studio 2017 and I want to put it in Azure DevOps.
What are the steps required to do this?

Comment: @DonBaechtel My answer and the documentation explains the process. Create a repo in Azure Devops, add a remote to your local repo, then push it to Azure Devops.