# Import a vs 2017 solution git repo into azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to use appcenter with azuredevops services.

- I have created a solution "HelloWorld" on local PC in VS 2017 and added to local Git repository
- I have created a project in AzureDevOps "MobileApps"

How do I import my new shiny solution in VS2017 "HelloWorld" into AzureDevOps?
Any walkthrough?

I can make it work if

- I start from azuredevops and clone in visual studio.Bcse I then get a prompt in visual studio to create a new solution in the new cloned repo.

But Cannot find a way to import a repository from Visual studio into AzureDevOps.

Links that i saw but did not work .Also outdated with azuredevops.

[How to Import project code from local machine to Azure Repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334570/how-to-import-project-code-from-local-machine-to-azure-repos)

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.jpaul.me/2018/10/importing-a-github-repo-to-azure-devops-repo/)?

Comment: What is the issue? when you click on "Import repository" and paste your git repo url, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be following these steps to add your local git repo to Azure DevOps

1. Create a git repo in Azure DevOps repos
2. Copy the clone url from Azure DevOps and use below command to configure your local repo to use Azure DevOps repo as the remote repo. Edit command from local git repo root folder.

`git remote add origin <url-from-Azure repos>`

Then you should be able to push your local content to Azure repos..you can use below commands

```
git add .
git commit -m 'your comment'
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply  I have done the command you suggested and get nothing in my folder I did git clone <myurl> and i get "nullreference exception encountered and then asks me for the password. Im new to git command so cant distinguish diff between remote and clone

Comment: You should be executing this command in the local git repo root folder.. Then perform a git add, commit and push