# Importing an existing local git repository into Azure Devops

Tags: github, azure-devops

My company has an old local git repository, which I'm trying to add to Azure Devops but so far, I've been unsuccessful (I've never setup a repository in Devops before, so I'm very new to this).

I've been trying to add this to devops by going into Repos > Import Repository, however when I attempt to import, I receive the following error:

[image]

I know this repository exists because I'm able to open this repository url via visual studio and work with the project within there, however when I attempt to import it into azure devops, I'm receiving that issue.

I've tried both providing authentication username & PAT....and I've attempted with no authentication.  Neither seems to work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong to get this imported into devops?
Thanks

Comment: On which agent do you run your pipeline? If you use Azure pipelines agents provided by Microsoft there should be no connectivity between the agent and your local git server. You could either create a self hosted agent and make this work, or  make your git available on a public service like github, bitbucket either as private or public.

Comment: Did you check these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334570/how-to-import-project-code-from-local-machine-to-azure-repos