# Create Azure Repo for Existing SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure, clone, repo

We have an existing SQL database on a SQL Server. We use Azure repos.
I would like to be able to create a repo for the SQL database.
Not sure what the proper steps are.
I can create an empty repo in azure devops and clone it to my local machine.
I can open up Visual Studio, how do I import the SQL database into a new project?
Once I have the SQL project I can push back up to azure devops with sync...push and create pull request.

Comment: I think this post might help you out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334570/how-to-import-project-code-from-local-machine-to-azure-repos

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to create a repo for the SQL database. . I can
> open up Visual Studio, how do I import the SQL database into a new
> project? Once I have the SQL project I can push back up to azure
> DevOps with sync…push and create a pull request.

There are multiple ways you can import your SQL database project into Azure Repos Refer to below:-

I created a Database object and imported it in an SQL Server project in VS code like below:-

[image]

[image]

There are 3 ways you can import this SQL project from your local machine to Azure DevOps:-

***Approach 1)***

When you create a new project in Azure DevOps a default repo with the same project name is created in the Azure DevOps organization. you can use the built-in authentication to import your repo in Azure DevOps, refer to below:-

[image]

I ran these commands in my VS studio code command line to import the SQL project to the Azure DevOps repo like below:-

```
git --version
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

[image]

Now copy the remote origin code from the Azure DevOps page above *Refer above Image* - **Push an existing repository from the command line** and push it to our Azure repos by logging into the Azure DevOps account like below:-

```
git remote add origin https://<org-name>@dev.azure.com/org/project-name/_git/project-name
git push -u origin --all
```

[image]

SQL project added to Azure DevOps repos like below:-

[image]

Now you can set up a build and run the SQL pipeline or even commit changes to your project and push it via git push in the same repo.

***Approach 2)***
Importing via GitHub.
You can save this entire SQL project in your GitHub account and import it to Azure DevOps like below:-

[image]

You can directly paste the Github repo URL and import it directly without any Authentication for the Public repository or Import it with Git authentication with PAT Token like below:-

[image]

Click Require authentication > Enter the Username and Password of your GitHub account and get the PAT from GitHub Account Settings > Developer settings > Personal access token > Generate new Token

[image]

[image]

Github repo got imported in Azure DevOps successfully.

[image]

***Approach 3)***

Import the Project from VS studio code like below:-

[image]

[image]

You can Push the code from Visual Studio to Azure DevOps Repo with the above option.

You can start creating a release pipeline and import the SQL project as an Artifact and run the pipeline like below:-

[image]